# Laravel Scout with Typesense Parameter fields is required

Tags: php, laravel

I've been trying to get Typesense working with Laravel Scout. I have installed and verified Typesense is running on both my local Macbook and on a DigitalOcean Ubuntu server. I also have the scout config set to match the model. Any time I try to import or communicate from Laravel to Typesense I get this error:

`php artisan scout:import App\\Models\\Module`

```
Parameter fields is required.
at vendor/typesense/typesense-php/src/ApiCall.php:344
```

I have `use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;` on the model along with `use Searchable`

And toSearchableArray() is there:

```
public function toSearchableArray()
    {
        return array_merge($this->toArray(), [
            'id' => (string) $this->id,
            'model' => $this->model,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at->timestamp,
        ]);
    }
```

My scout config for the model:

```
Module::class => [
                'collection-schema' => [
                    'fields' => [
                        [
                            'name' => 'id',
                            'type' => 'string',
                        ],
                        [
                            'name' => 'uuid',
                            'type' => 'string',
                        ],
                        [
                            'name' => 'created_at',
                            'type' => 'int64',
                        ],
                    ],
                    'default_sorting_field' => 'created_at',
                ],
                'search-parameters' => [
                    'query_by' => 'uuid'
                ],
            ]
```

Health check works:

```
curl http://localhost:8108/health
{"ok":true}
```

I have cleared all the things over and over:

`php artisan optimize:clear` `php artisan config:clear` .... desperation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is caused by the configuration of your config/scout.php.

Unfortunately it is not written anywhere but, you have to make sure that you have imported on top of "config/scout.php", the class of your model, in your case: App\Models\Module.

So, open: config/scout.php, and, on top, before "return [" add this line:

```
use App\Models\Module;
```

In the end you should get a result like this:

config\scout.php:

```
<?php
use App\Models\Module;

return [
......
];
```

Now you can try to do the import command.